# Окно всплывающее в заданное время

Tags: php, javascript

Как создать всплывающее окно, которое будет выводиться только по ночам и по выходным?

Comment: А может вам это сделать с помощью JavaScript? И нагрузка на сервер меньше и не надо считать разницу между часовыми поясами (Вдруг я с Узбекистана а сервер в Латинской Америке у что? У меня понедельник у них воскресенье У меня утро у них ночь)
P.S: JavaScript есть даже в допотопных браузерах а Java must be loaded by user поэтому я за JavaScript!

Comment: Спасибо. Меня устраивает первые 2 варианта.

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы ночью во всплывающем окне выводился один текст, а по выходным другой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="charset" content="utf-8">
    <title>Окно</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #mywindow{
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 25%;
                    left: 25%;
                    width: 50%;
                    height: 50%;
                    background-color: #FFF9AE;
                    visibility: hidden;
                }
        #closewin{
            position: absolute;
            top: 3px;
            right: 3px;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            background-color: #FFF9AE;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function showWindow(){
            var myWindow = document.getElementById("mywindow");
            var nowDate = new Date();
            if(nowDate.getDay() == 0 || nowDate.getDay() == 6 ||( nowDate.getHours() <= 8 || nowDate.getHours() >= 21 )){
                myWindow.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
        function closeWin(){
            var myWindow = document.getElementById("mywindow");
            myWindow.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        window.onload = showWindow;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mywindow"><div id="closewin" onclick="closeWin()">Закрыть</div>Допустим что это окно...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вариант 2 (самый лёгкий):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="charset" content="utf-8">
    <title>Окно</title>
    <script>
        function showWindow(){
            var nowDate = new Date();
            if(nowDate.getDay() == 0 || nowDate.getDay() == 6 ||( nowDate.getHours() <= 8 || nowDate.getHours() >= 21 )){
                alert("Сообщение");
            }
        }
        window.onload = showWindow;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Вариант 3.0 (браузер может его не допустить):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="charset" content="utf-8">
    <title>Окно</title>
    <script>
        function messageWindow(title, msg){
            var width="480", height="350";
            var left = (screen.width/2) - width/2;
            var top = (screen.height/2) - height/2;
            var styleStr = 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbar=no,resizable=no,copyhistory=yes,width='+width+',height='+height+',left='+left+',top='+top+',screenX='+left+',screenY='+top;
            var msgWindow = window.open("","msgWindow", styleStr);
            var head = '<head><title>'+title+'</title></head>';
            var body = '<center>'+msg+'<p><form><input type="button" value="   Ok   " onClick="self.close()"></form>';
            msgWindow.document.write(head + body);
        }
        function showWindow(){
            var nowDate = new Date();
            if(nowDate.getDay() == 0 || nowDate.getDay() == 6 ||( nowDate.getHours() <= 8 || nowDate.getHours() >= 21 )){
                messageWindow("Заголовок окна","Содержимое окна");
            }
        }
        window.onload = showWindow;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Вариант 3.1 (с кнопкой браузер не блокирует!):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="charset" content="utf-8">
    <title>Окно</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <script>
        function messageWindow(title, msg){
            var width="480", height="350";
            var left = (screen.width/2) - width/2;
            var top = (screen.height/2) - height/2;
            var styleStr = 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbar=no,resizable=no,copyhistory=yes,width='+width+',height='+height+',left='+left+',top='+top+',screenX='+left+',screenY='+top;
            var msgWindow = window.open("","msgWindow", styleStr);
            var head = '<head><title>'+title+'</title></head>';
            var body = '<center>'+msg+'<p><form><input type="button" value="   Ok   " onClick="self.close()"></form>';
            msgWindow.document.write(head + body);
        }
        function showWindow(){
            var nowDate = new Date();
            if(nowDate.getDay() == 0 || nowDate.getDay() == 6 ||( nowDate.getHours() <= 8 || nowDate.getHours() >= 21 )){
                mybutton = document.getElementById("hiddenbutton");
                mybutton.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
        window.onload = showWindow;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="hiddenbutton" value="Открыть окно" onclick="messageWindow('Заголовок окна','Содержимое окна');">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: То есть это вывод окна в выходные? Верно?

Comment: А как ночью сделать?

Comment: А что есть "ночь" это с 21 до 8 часов?

Comment: Я имел ввиду не в выходные ночью. А выходные круглосуточно, и ночью в любой день. Извените, что неправильно выразился.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Работает. Очень мне помогли. А не подскажите, как кнопку закрытия для этого окна сделать?

Comment: @Pavlik290592 вот 3 варианта 2 на 5рку а один... можно сделать кнопку типа "открыть окно" появлющейся и при клике на неё будет открываться окно а без кнопки/ссылки браузер блокирует открытие окна (умный зараза :)) сделать кнопку для 3 варианта или вас первые 2 устроят? (В 3 ем новое окно браузера открывается с сообщением (не на весь экран и без кнопок браузера))

Comment: @pavlik290592 В общем вам и кому интересно сделал 4 варианта 3.1 рабочий а 3.0 для примера "умности" браузера

Answer (score 0):

Получать методом date() время, и выставлять сервер по мск. времени
Дальше мы парсим день недели. И воля)) Функцию можно прописать типо

> ```
> $datB=date("w");
> if($datB=='Saturday' or $datB=='Sunday') 
> {
> //Ваш скрипт в субботу и воскресение по времени сервера!!!!!
> }
> ```

Comment: А можно ли сделать, чтобы учитывалось не серверное время, а время с компа посетителя сайта? Так как сайт не локальный, а на много городов, а часовые пояса разные.

Comment: А Вам критично именно php? Не лучше ли для этого использовать не php, a JavaScript например.

Comment: Не критично. Только я не знаю, как на Ява сделать. Я правильно понимаю, что ява может быть неустановлена у пользователя, или заблокирована в браузере?

Comment: Да может быть заблокировано, но сейчас мало более не менее функциональных сайтов у которых так или иначе не использовался бы JavaScript. Т.к не припомню, методов вывода пользовательской даты на php. http://ab-w.net/JS/JS_date.php#Date тут приведено несколько простых способов вывести время при помощи JS

Comment: JAVA я не знаю. Не могли бы помочь написать функцию вывода всплывающего окна в определённое время?

Comment: @Pavlik290592 JavaScript это совсем не Java

Comment: Счас напишу...

Comment: А можно с помощью JavaScript занести в переменную дату, а потом эту переменную использовать в PHP?

Comment: Если передать её AJAX то да а зачем вам это в PHP?